# Hibernate Envers: @Audited on a subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a classic inheritance persistence with entities *Parent* and *Child*, where *Child* extends *Parent*. Class *Parent* is abstract, while *Child* is not.

**I want to audit *Child*.** This entity is under my control, while *Parent* is not. Besides, it has many other subclasses which need not be audited. The inheritance strategy on the whole hierarchy is *JOINED*.

So I have annotated *Child* with *@Audited* and additionally with *@AuditOverride(forClass = Parent.class)*.

What I get is this error:

> "org.hibernate.MappingException: Entity 'Child' is audited, but its superclass: 'Parent' is not."

By the way, I'm using envers 4.0.1.Final version.

**Does anyone know how can I achieve this?**
I've tried removing *@Audited* in *Child* class, removing *@AuditOverride*, using deprecated *auditParents* in *@Audited* annotation, but nothing seems to work.

This is the Parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public class Parent {
    public Parent() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "base_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer baseId;

    @Column(name = "base_field")
    private String baseField;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And this is my Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@DiscriminatorValue("CHILD")
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = Parent.class)
public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
        super();
    }

    @Column(name = "child_field")
    private String childField;

    // getters and setters
}
```

This are the entities:

```
CREATE  TABLE `REVINFO` (
  `REV` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `REVTSTMP` BIGINT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`REV`)
);

CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `base_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `base_field` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`base_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `base_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child_field` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`base_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `child_AUD` (
  `base_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `REV` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `REVTYPE` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_field` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`base_id`,`REV`)
);
```

Here is a test case:

```
public class EnversInheritanceTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void inheritanceTest() {

        this.entityManager = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        Child child = this.createChild();
        this.saveChild(child);

        this.modifyChild(child);
        this.saveChild(child);

        Assert.assertNotNull(child.getBaseId());
        Assert.assertNotNull(this.getOriginalRevision(child.getBaseId()));

        Child original = this.getOriginalChild(child.getBaseId());

        Assert.assertNotNull(original);
        Assert.assertEquals("child", original.getChildField());

    }

    private Child createChild() {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setBaseField("base");
        child.setChildField("child");
        child.setType("CHILD");
        return child;
    }

    private void saveChild(Child child) {
        this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        this.entityManager.persist(child);
        // We need to commit in order to trigger Envers magic
        this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    private void modifyChild(Child child) {
        child.setBaseField("foo");
        child.setChildField("bar");
    }

    public Child getOriginalChild(Serializable id) {
        Object queryResult = this.getAuditReader().createQuery()
                .forEntitiesAtRevision(Child.class, this.getOriginalRevision(id))
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
                .getSingleResult();
        return (Child) queryResult;
    }

    private Number getOriginalRevision(Serializable id) {
        AuditProjection minRevNumberAuditProjection = AuditEntity.revisionNumber().min();
        Number revision = (Number) this.getAuditReader().createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(Child.class, false, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
                .addProjection(minRevNumberAuditProjection)
                .getSingleResult();

        return revision;
    }

    private AuditReader getAuditReader() {
        return AuditReaderFactory.get(this.entityManager);
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Most probably it's a bug in `hibernate-envers`. See: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2489543

Comment: Such mapping works fine in hibernate 5. One solution would be to update hibernate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very good question. There was the [same discussion](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/229564?db=5) on the `jboss` developers forum in 2013 year. And the answer was from [the founder and project lead of Hibernate Enver](https://developer.jboss.org/people/adamw):

> You would have to get the superclass audited somehow. Currently
>   there's no other way to specify such metadata except for annotations.

In the same discussion tree, according to the fact that a parent class should also be annotated, there was suggested to annotate them in Runtime. But this decision seems to be ugly and is not suitable in your case: you can annotate the parent class manually.

As a workaround, if you don't want the parent class being audited, you can try to create a base abstract `MappedSuperClass` which essentially will be the same as `Parent`, while `Parent` will be just its descendant, and then try to put `@AuditOverride` again for the `Child` class. It is possible that it will "skip" audit for `Parent` class and do it for `Child`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to mark parent and child classes with @Audited annotation 
but for parent class add @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)